# Is there a way to make filled + rounded icons in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, material-icons

I just wanted to ask, if there is any way of making an icon in Android Studio that is rounded and filled or rounded and outlined at the same time. Because, I like the rounded icons more but if I add a rounded icon, I can't make it outlined. I also don't want to import an svg.
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
OutlinedButton(
    onClick = { Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is a Circular Button with a Icon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() },
    modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
    shape = CircleShape,
    border = BorderStroke(5.dp, Color(0XFF0F9D58)),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(contentColor = Color.Blue)
) {
    // Adding an Icon "Add" inside the Button
    Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "content description", tint = Color(0XFF0F9D58))
}
```

More in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-circular-button-with-an-icon-in-android-jetpack-compose/)...